search for multiple words in object property
I have an array of objects, shown here in a somewhat reduced form.
I want to be able to search for different search terms. On the one hand, I would like to get all objects that contain all search terms, and on the other hand, all objects that contain any search term. The number of search terms is dynamic.
e.g. for (x1 and x2) , (x1 or x2)
Of course I can do this with a loop, but is there also a way to solve the problem with filter ... include ...
[
    {
      "produkt": "Produkt 1",
      "description": "x1, x2, x3, x4"
    },
    {
      "produkt": "Produkt 1",
      "description": "x2, x3"
    },
    {
      "produkt": "Produkt 1",
      "description": "x1, x4"
    }
]


Since filter uses a callback function, you should be able to just do all your checks in that. What problem did you run into when you tried implementing that?

In the filter callback function, you can use Array.every() or Array.some() to test whether a property matches all or any of the search terms.

Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>).  It's obvious you already know [ask] given the fact you have 1000+ rep.

This might be a little convoluted, but if you want a reusable function you can call with your products and search terms this is an efficient way to get both the products with all search terms and those with any of them. It will also only iterate through your product list once, though it will iterate through search terms multiple times.
Using Typescript:
const produkts = [
        {
            "produkt": "1",
            "description": "x1, x2, x3, x4"
        },
        {
            "produkt": "2",
            "description": "x3"
        }
    ]

    const findProdukts = (produkts, searchTerms: string[]) => {
        let results = {
            matchesAll: [],
            matchesSome: []
        }

        return produkts.reduce((acc: {matchesAll: [any], matchesSome: [any]}, val: {produkt: string, description: string}) => {
            return {
                matchesAll: searchTerms.every(search => val.description.includes(search)) ? [...acc.matchesAll, val] : [...acc.matchesAll],
                matchesSome: searchTerms.some(search => val.description.includes(search)) ? [...acc.matchesSome, val] : [...acc.matchesSome]
            }
        }, results)
    }

    console.log(findProdukts(produkts, ["x2", "x3"]))

Using Javascript:


const produkts = [
    {
        "produkt": "1",
        "description": "x1, x2, x3, x4"
    },
    {
        "produkt": "2",
        "description": "x3"
    }
]

const findProdukts = (produkts, searchTerms) => {
    let results = {
        matchesAll: [],
        matchesSome: []
    }

    return produkts.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return {
            matchesAll: searchTerms.every(search => val.description.includes(search)) ? [...acc.matchesAll, val] : [...acc.matchesAll],
            matchesSome: searchTerms.some(search => val.description.includes(search)) ? [...acc.matchesSome, val] : [...acc.matchesSome]
        }
    }, results)
}

console.log(findProdukts(produkts, ["x2", "x3"]))




The original question doesn't seem to be using Typescript (or at least it's not tagged), so this might be confusing to the OP.

thanks! I learned a lot!

If you are looking for a performance, this solution should work very well:
const produkts = [
  {
    produkt: 'Produkt 1',
    description: 'x1, x2, x3, x4',
  },
  {
    produkt: 'Produkt 1',
    description: 'x2, x3',
  },
  {
    produkt: 'Produkt 1',
    description: 'x1, x4',
  },
];

const filterItems = (produkts = [], searchTerms = []) => {
  const regexps = searchTerms.map((searchTerm) => new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i'));
  const results = { containAll: [], containAny: [] };

  produkts.forEach((produkt) => {
    const matches = regexps.map((regexp) => regexp.test(produkt.description)).filter((isMatch) => isMatch).length;

    if (matches) {
      results.containAny.push(produkt);
      if (matches === regexps.length) {
        results.containAll.push(produkt);
      }
    }
  });

  return results;
};

console.log(filterItems(produkts, ['x1', 'x2']));

The function is optimized by using regular expressions for flexible and efficient matching, counting matches for each product to avoid unnecessary operations, and directly accumulating results without creating new arrays, reducing memory overhead.
Filters a list of products based on a list of search terms. It creates regular expressions for each search term and checks if the product descriptions match. It categorizes products into two groups: containAll (products that match all search terms) and containAny (products that match at least one search term). The function returns an object containing these two categories.

I suggest a different approach by iterating searchTerms only once for every product by counting matches.
For the result compare matches against search terms and add the product to the appropriate property.


const
    findProducts = (products, searchTerms) => products.reduce(
        (r, product) => {
            const count = searchTerms.reduce((t, search) => t + product.description.includes(search), 0);
            return {
                matchesAll: count === searchTerms.length
                    ? [...r.matchesAll, product]
                    : r.matchesAll,
                matchesSome: count
                    ? [...r.matchesSome, product]
                    : r.matchesSome
            };
        },
        { matchesAll: [], matchesSome: [] }
    ),
    products = [{ produkt: "1", description: "x1, x2, x3, x4" }, { produkt: "2", description: "x3" }];

console.log(findProducts(products, ["x2", "x3"]))
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }



